# How to generate SignatureValue from Signature XML String in OpenSAML

Tags: java, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml, opensaml

I am trying IDP initiated login only on SAML2.0. I have an XML string of Signature block which I need to generate SignatureValue using OpenSAML.

Using Java Security I am able to do like below and able to return the generated Signature value but while I am sending to the service provider it is sending 401-Unauthorized, where I realized I need to use OpenSAML in place of java security package.

How can I generate SignatureValue from the below XML using OpenSAML?

Note: I do not have any POJO classes of my SOAP XML.

**Signature Block:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
   <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
      <Reference URI="#Body-a23jlkasdjfo2urojsdklf">
         <Transforms>
            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
         </Transforms>
         <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
         <DigestValue>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
   </SignedInfo>
   <SignatureValue />
   <KeyInfo>
      <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#SecurityToken-a23jlkasdjfo2urojsdklf" />
      </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
   </KeyInfo>
</Signature>
```

**Java Code:**

```
public static String generateSignatureValue(String signatureMessage, String signatureAlgorithm,
        String privateKeyString)
                throws Exception {

            org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();

        Canonicalizer canon = Canonicalizer.getInstance(Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);
        byte[] canonXmlBytes = canon.canonicalize(signatureMessage.getBytes());
        
            KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpecPKCS8 = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyString));
            PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpecPKCS8);
        
            java.security.Signature rsaSha1Signature = java.security.Signature.getInstance(signatureAlgorithm);
            rsaSha1Signature.initSign(privateKey);
            rsaSha1Signature.update(canonXmlBytes);
            byte[] signed2 = rsaSha1Signature.sign();
        
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signed2);

    }
```

Comment: In OpenSAML V3 the signature is typicallu generated when preparing to send the message using a specific binding. How will you be sending the AuythenMessage? HTTP Redirect?

Comment: I am planning to use OpenSAML V4. The ServiceProvider API call is getting done by HTTP POST SOAP request (soap:envelop message). Once the Service Provider authenticates this message it sends to redirect the API. Sending the X509 certificate under soap:header -> wsse:Security -> wsse:BinarySecurityToken which is outside of Signature block.